# number of active s-boxes in a block cipher?

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher, s-boxes

How can we find the minimum number of differentially  active s-boxes in a block cipher (actually a Feistel network with several input cells) in a truncated characteristic form? In a recursive algorithm when we get to the situation that there are binary cases, I don't know what to do? For example when I get a xor of two nonzero characteristics, there are two cases nonzero and zero, How can recursive algorithm be applied in this state?

Comment: Explain more, by example. Your second paragraph is incomprehensible to me.

Answer (score 2):

There many methods to find the number of active sboxes such as:

1. search algorithm , you input different scenarios , it is time-expensive process.
2. Matsui algorithm. [code](https://github.com/kste/matsui)
3. Mixed integer linear programming.

   I recommend you to try MIxed integer linear programming

References:

[Differential and Linear Cryptanalysis using Mixed-Integer Linear Programming](https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/article-2080.pdf)

[Automatic Security Evaluation of Block Ciphers with S-bP Structures against Related-key Differential Attacks](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/547.pdf)

[New Impossible Differential Search Tool from Design and Cryptanalysis Aspects](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2e22/42b99526246e3a12c90d19638a2065711f69.pdf)